# Through the API endpoint /categories/{categoryId}/products I cannot retrieve products of the specified category, returns empty array

Tags: magento2, category, rest-api

I'm working with Magento 2 **REST API** and trying to retrieve **products of a specific category**, but I'm running into an issue: on my Magento dashboard i can see that in a specific category there are some products, but when i use the endpoint `/categories/{categoryId}/products` it only returns an empty array. Where's the mistake? Do I have to configurate something in my dashboard?

Thanks!

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: I'm actually using Postman to do the request, so I don't have a code to share with you. It's a simple GET request to the specified endpoint.